# Do not propagate test transaction to the tested method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have this setup:

- A method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)`. (The reason is that there are some 3rd party API calls that I don't want to run in a transaction. The rest of the method sets up a transaction manually via `TransactionTemplate`)
- A test that sets up some objects in the DB and calls my method.

Now I want my test to run in a transaction so that the DB is properly cleared after it finishes. But at the same time, I need to prevent that transaction to propagate to my method because it specifically forbids so.

Is there any way to achieve that?